# Application.Openforms for a control inside a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: example of the gui]

I am trying to get access to a button that is inside a user control which itself is inside another window.
I have tried both the lines of code provided below.

```
Button manpanel = Application.OpenForms["STAFFHOMEMENU"].Controls["MASTERDATABASE"] as Button;
```

```
Button manpanel = Application.OpenForms["STAFFHOME"].Controls["MAINPANEL"].Controls["STAFFHOMEMENU"].Controls["MASTERDATABASE"] as Button;
```

Any fixes or alternative ways of accomplishing this would be great, Sorry if the message is a little unclear.

When the code is run with either of these lines I get the following error :
"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: So, what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: apologies I should have put that in the description, when running with either of the lines above I get the following error : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: See the duplicate question, but I'm suspecting the issue is that your form names are wrong.  If OpenFormns can't find the form with the given name, it will return null, and then you are trying to dereference properties on a null.

Comment: Alrighty then I'll have another look and see what I can do.

Comment: OK an interesting update, I checked the names and they seem correct, I chucked a bit of code to check how many forms are open, ' int testing2 = Application.OpenForms.Count;' when run it gets back 2 which is equivalent to the number of forms open but does not include the user control that I am trying to access. Would there happen to be an opencontrol option instead of openform?

Comment: Break it out into distinct steps. Here's a [Picture](https://pasteboard.co/ChVWPyeeOHri.png) to help you. Obviously change the names of the types to what you've got in your application.

Comment: It seems embarrassing that I didn't think to do it that way, ill have a bash and get back to you about it.

Comment: ...and you can add `else` blocks on all of those `if` statements to let you know which part is returning `null` and causing your issue.

Comment: Followed your advice and put this in : UserControl user = MAINPANEL.Controls[0] as UserControl;
                Button button = user.Controls["MASTERDATABASE"] as Button;
                button.Enabled = false;
                button.BackColor= Color.Green; seems to work great